# Xml file with same element as child and parent read and set to object

Tags: java, xml

I have a Object called Student like this

```
class Student{
  int a;
  String name;
  List<Student> childStudents;
}
```

and my xml looks like this

```
<root>
   <student>
      <a>1</a>
      <name>ABC</name>
   </student>
   <student>
      <a>2</a>
      <name>XYZ</name>
      <student>
           <a>3</a>
           <name>PQR</name>
       </student>
   </student>
</root>
```

Now what I want is read the XML and fill the values to Student Objects, in first Student Object as per XML only have values "a" and "name" only it doesn't have List of child students but in second element in xml has "a,name" and child student as well which is same as parent object student "a,name, and list of students", so what I want is as per xml values fill the objects with first studnet like this

```
Student
[ a =1 
  name = "ABC"
  listofStudents = null;
]
```

and Second Object like this

```
Student
[ a =2 
  name = "XYZ"
  listofStudents = (size)1;
            Student[
               a = 3
               name = "PQR"
               listofStudents = null;
            ]
]
```

Any One did same please attach link, extract scenario isn't same just sample simplified way I mentioned in the Question to get understand

I tried something like this

```
public void A(){
    nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("student");
    for (int msgIndex = 0; msgIndex < nodeList.getLength(); msgIndex++) {
            Node message = nodeList.item(msgIndex);
            if (message.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element eElement = (Element) message;
                String msgName = eElement.getAttribute("a");
                String msgCateg = eElement.getAttribute("name");


                Student msg = new Student();
                msg.setMsgName(msgName);
                msg.setMsgA(msgCateg);            

            }
        }
}
```

**2nd Attempt for solution I tried was**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by sadeeshal on 3/30/2016.
 */
public class Book {

    String author;
    double price;
    String pubdate;
    List<Book> listOfBooks = new ArrayList<Book>();

    public void addBookToList(Book b) {
        getListOfBooks().add(b);
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getPubdate() {
        return pubdate;
    }

    public void setPubdate(String pubdate) {
        this.pubdate = pubdate;
    }

    public List<Book> getListOfBooks() {
        return listOfBooks;
    }

    public void setListOfBooks(List<Book> listOfBooks) {
        this.listOfBooks = listOfBooks;
    }
}
```

and XML Read

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by sadeeshal on 3/30/2016.
 */
public class XML {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        XML xml = new XML();
        xml.readXML();
    }

    public void readXML(){

        try {
            File file = new File("C:/Users/sadeeshal/Downloads/A.xml");
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(file);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("book");
            Book bookParent = new Book();
            read(nodeList, bookParent);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void read( NodeList nList,Book bookParent){
        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                String name = eElement.getElementsByTagName("author").item(0).getTextContent();
                String pric = eElement.getElementsByTagName("price").item(0).getTextContent();
                String pub  =  eElement .getElementsByTagName("pubdate").item(0).getTextContent();

                Book book = new Book();
                book.setAuthor(name);
                book.setPrice(Double.parseDouble(pric));
                book.setPubdate(pub);

                if(nNode.hasChildNodes()){
                   read(((Element) nNode).getElementsByTagName("book"),book);
                   bookParent.addBookToList(book);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<books>
    <book>
        <author>Carson</author>
        <price>31.95</price>
        <pubdate>05/01/2001</pubdate>
        <book>
            <author>CarsonCild</author>
            <price>1.95</price>
            <pubdate>05/01/2011</pubdate>
        </book>
    </book>
    <book>
            <author>CarsonTwo</author>
            <price>30.95</price>
            <pubdate>05/01/2101</pubdate>
    </book>
</books>
```

and it got loaded as follows

[image]

But what actually needs to be happen is not like img carsonChild should only have single object under the array of listofbooks not at a parent

Comment: What is the question? can you re-write it to make clear what you're asking?

Comment: Hi @PedroG.Dias please check now

Comment: I have tried something like this, mentioned in the question it self. Duno how to set sub student correctly read and it to parent student

Answer (score 0):

At ReadXML By using the levels this can be fixed.(solution for 2nd ) so automatically get fixed the first one as well

```
XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();
            NodeList links = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("books/book", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

[image]

See the attachment of object creation